# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' for table with large amount of rows

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to create a CRUD operation for a table with almost 40 rows and getting the following error.
I have created similar CRUD projects before but with much lesser number of rows which have ran fine therefore this error is a bit strange

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Master
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.example.springbootcrudexample3.SpringBootCrudExample3Application.main(SpringBootCrudExample3Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Master
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:772) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I am following the regular `Controller`,`Entity`,`Repository`,`Service` methodology

I have tried Answers to similar questions but they seem to mention missing dependancies in pom.xml which are already here
Latest changes where made based on this [answer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/solved-org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified-for-entity-class) , also these seem to work for simpler tables ,as soon as rows and their types increase this problem pops up

Have pasted rest of the code below and formatted it for easier reading
Apologies for the longer code format
Thanks for the help in Advance

Entity

```
package com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

//@Data
//@AllArgsConstructor @Getter @Setter
//@NoArgsConstructor 
@Entity
@Table(name="EVENT_MASTER_TEST")
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
public class Event_Master {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name="State")
    private String state;
    @Column(name="Waterfall")
    private String waterfall;
    @Column(name="ChannelName")
    private String channelname;
    @Column(name="CLMSegmentName")
    private String clmsegmentname;
    @Column(name="Execution_Sequence")
    private long executionsequence;
    @Column(name="Updated_On")
    private String updatedon;
    @Column(name="EventId")
    private long eventid;
    @Column(name="CampTriggerId")
    private long camptriggerid;
    @Column(name="CreativeId1")
    private long creativeid1;
    @Column(name="CampaignId")
    private long campaignid;
    @Column(name="RankedPickListStory_Id")
    private long rankedpickliststoryid;
    @Column(name="Communication_Cooloff")
    private long communicationcooloff;
    @Column(name="Event_Limit")
    private String eventlimit;
    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="ExtCreativeKey")
    private String extcreativekey;
    @Column(name="SenderKey")
    private String senderkey;
    @Column(name="Timeslot_Name")
    private String timeslotname;
    @Column(name="Timeslot_Id")
    private long timeslotid;
    @Column(name="Number_Of_Recommendation")
    private long numberofrecommendation;
    @Column(name="Start_Date_ID")
    private long startdateid;
    @Column(name="End_Date_ID")
    private long enddateid;
    @Column(name="Creative1")
    private String creative1;
    @Column(name="Replaced_Query")
    private String replacedquery;
    @Column(name="Website_URL")
    private String websiteurl;
    @Column(name="CampaignThemeName")
    private String campaignthemename;
    @Column(name="MicroSegmentName")
    private String microsegmentname;
    @Column(name="CampaignName")
    private String campaignname;
    @Column(name="Description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name="Replaced_Query_Bill")
    private String replacedquerybill;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Filter_Logic")
    private String recommendationfilterlogic;
    @Column(name="Event_Control_Group_Percentage")
    private double eventcontrolgrouppercentage;
    @Column(name="Communication_Template_ID")
    private long communicationtemplateid;
    @Column(name="Inserted_On")
    private String insertedon;
    @Column(name="Event_Type_ID")
    private long eventtypeid;
    @Column(name="CLMSegmentId")
    private long clmsegmentid;
    @Column(name="Event_Response_Days")
    private long eventresponsedays;
    @Column(name="Reminder_Parent_Event_Id")
    private long reminderparenteventid;
    @Column(name="Reminder_Days")
    private long reminderdays;
    @Column(name="Arms")
    private long arms;
    @Column(name="Is_MAB_Driven")
    private long ismabdriven;
    @Column(name="Follows_Waterfall")
    private long followswaterfall;
    @Column(name="Is_Good_Time")
    private long isgoodtime;
    @Column(name="Is_On_Demand")
    private long isondemand;
    @Column(name="Condition")
    private long condition;
    @Column(name="No_Of_Personalization")
    private long noofpersonalization;
    @Column(name="Offer_Code1")
    private String offercode1;
    public   long getid(){ return  id ;}
    public   String getstate(){ return  state ;}
    public   String getwaterfall(){ return  waterfall ;}
    public   String getchannelname(){ return  channelname ;}
    public   String getclmsegmentname(){ return  clmsegmentname ;}
    public   long getexecutionsequence(){ return  executionsequence ;}
    public   String getupdatedon(){ return  updatedon ;}
    public   long geteventid(){ return  eventid ;}
    public   long getcamptriggerid(){ return  camptriggerid ;}
    public   long getcreativeid1(){ return  creativeid1 ;}
    public   long getcampaignid(){ return  campaignid ;}
    public   long getrankedpickliststoryid(){ return  rankedpickliststoryid ;}
    public   long getcommunicationcooloff(){ return  communicationcooloff ;}
    public   String geteventlimit(){ return  eventlimit ;}
    public   String getname(){ return  name ;}
    public   String getextcreativekey(){ return  extcreativekey ;}
    public   String getsenderkey(){ return  senderkey ;}
    public   String gettimeslotname(){ return  timeslotname ;}
    public   long gettimeslotid(){ return  timeslotid ;}
    public   long getnumberofrecommendation(){ return  numberofrecommendation ;}
    public   long getstartdateid(){ return  startdateid ;}
    public   long getenddateid(){ return  enddateid ;}
    public   String getcreative1(){ return  creative1 ;}
    public   String getreplacedquery(){ return  replacedquery ;}
    public   String getwebsiteurl(){ return  websiteurl ;}
    public   String getcampaignthemename(){ return  campaignthemename ;}
    public   String getmicrosegmentname(){ return  microsegmentname ;}
    public   String getcampaignname(){ return  campaignname ;}
    public   String getdescription(){ return  description ;}
    public   String getreplacedquerybill(){ return  replacedquerybill ;}
    public   String getrecommendationfilterlogic(){ return  recommendationfilterlogic ;}
    public   double geteventcontrolgrouppercentage(){ return  eventcontrolgrouppercentage ;}
    public   long getcommunicationtemplateid(){ return  communicationtemplateid ;}
    public   String getinsertedon(){ return  insertedon ;}
    public   long geteventtypeid(){ return  eventtypeid ;}
    public   long getclmsegmentid(){ return  clmsegmentid ;}
    public   long geteventresponsedays(){ return  eventresponsedays ;}
    public   long getreminderparenteventid(){ return  reminderparenteventid ;}
    public   long getreminderdays(){ return  reminderdays ;}
    public   long getarms(){ return  arms ;}
    public   long getismabdriven(){ return  ismabdriven ;}
    public   long getfollowswaterfall(){ return  followswaterfall ;}
    public   long getisgoodtime(){ return  isgoodtime ;}
    public   long getisondemand(){ return  isondemand ;}
    public   long getcondition(){ return  condition ;}
    public   long getnoofpersonalization(){ return  noofpersonalization ;}
    public   String getoffercode1(){ return  offercode1 ;}
    public  void setid( long id ){ this.id=id;}
    public  void setstate( String state ){ this.state=state;}
    public  void setwaterfall( String waterfall ){ this.waterfall=waterfall;}
    public  void setchannelname( String channelname ){ this.channelname=channelname;}
    public  void setclmsegmentname( String clmsegmentname ){ this.clmsegmentname=clmsegmentname;}
    public  void setexecutionsequence( long executionsequence ){ this.executionsequence=executionsequence;}
    public  void setupdatedon( String updatedon ){ this.updatedon=updatedon;}
    public  void seteventid( long eventid ){ this.eventid=eventid;}
    public  void setcamptriggerid( long camptriggerid ){ this.camptriggerid=camptriggerid;}
    public  void setcreativeid1( long creativeid1 ){ this.creativeid1=creativeid1;}
    public  void setcampaignid( long campaignid ){ this.campaignid=campaignid;}
    public  void setrankedpickliststoryid( long rankedpickliststoryid ){ this.rankedpickliststoryid=rankedpickliststoryid;}
    public  void setcommunicationcooloff( long communicationcooloff ){ this.communicationcooloff=communicationcooloff;}
    public  void seteventlimit( String eventlimit ){ this.eventlimit=eventlimit;}
    public  void setname( String name ){ this.name=name;}
    public  void setextcreativekey( String extcreativekey ){ this.extcreativekey=extcreativekey;}
    public  void setsenderkey( String senderkey ){ this.senderkey=senderkey;}
    public  void settimeslotname( String timeslotname ){ this.timeslotname=timeslotname;}
    public  void settimeslotid( long timeslotid ){ this.timeslotid=timeslotid;}
    public  void setnumberofrecommendation( long numberofrecommendation ){ this.numberofrecommendation=numberofrecommendation;}
    public  void setstartdateid( long startdateid ){ this.startdateid=startdateid;}
    public  void setenddateid( long enddateid ){ this.enddateid=enddateid;}
    public  void setcreative1( String creative1 ){ this.creative1=creative1;}
    public  void setreplacedquery( String replacedquery ){ this.replacedquery=replacedquery;}
    public  void setwebsiteurl( String websiteurl ){ this.websiteurl=websiteurl;}
    public  void setcampaignthemename( String campaignthemename ){ this.campaignthemename=campaignthemename;}
    public  void setmicrosegmentname( String microsegmentname ){ this.microsegmentname=microsegmentname;}
    public  void setcampaignname( String campaignname ){ this.campaignname=campaignname;}
    public  void setdescription( String description ){ this.description=description;}
    public  void setreplacedquerybill( String replacedquerybill ){ this.replacedquerybill=replacedquerybill;}
    public  void setrecommendationfilterlogic( String recommendationfilterlogic ){ this.recommendationfilterlogic=recommendationfilterlogic;}
    public  void seteventcontrolgrouppercentage( double eventcontrolgrouppercentage ){ this.eventcontrolgrouppercentage=eventcontrolgrouppercentage;}
    public  void setcommunicationtemplateid( long communicationtemplateid ){ this.communicationtemplateid=communicationtemplateid;}
    public  void setinsertedon( String insertedon ){ this.insertedon=insertedon;}
    public  void seteventtypeid( long eventtypeid ){ this.eventtypeid=eventtypeid;}
    public  void setclmsegmentid( long clmsegmentid ){ this.clmsegmentid=clmsegmentid;}
    public  void seteventresponsedays( long eventresponsedays ){ this.eventresponsedays=eventresponsedays;}
    public  void setreminderparenteventid( long reminderparenteventid ){ this.reminderparenteventid=reminderparenteventid;}
    public  void setreminderdays( long reminderdays ){ this.reminderdays=reminderdays;}
    public  void setarms( long arms ){ this.arms=arms;}
    public  void setismabdriven( long ismabdriven ){ this.ismabdriven=ismabdriven;}
    public  void setfollowswaterfall( long followswaterfall ){ this.followswaterfall=followswaterfall;}
    public  void setisgoodtime( long isgoodtime ){ this.isgoodtime=isgoodtime;}
    public  void setisondemand( long isondemand ){ this.isondemand=isondemand;}
    public  void setcondition( long condition ){ this.condition=condition;}
    public  void setnoofpersonalization( long noofpersonalization ){ this.noofpersonalization=noofpersonalization;}
    public  void setoffercode1( String offercode1 ){ this.offercode1=offercode1;}

}
```

Service

```
package com.example.springbootcrudexample3.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Master;
import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.repository.Event_Repository;

@Service
public class Event_Service {
    
    @Autowired
    private Event_Repository e_repository;
    
    // Save Product Methods
    public Event_Master saveEvent(Event_Master event) {
        return e_repository.save(event);
    }
    
    public List<Event_Master> saveEvents(List<Event_Master> events){
        return e_repository.saveAll(events);
    }   
    
    // Get Product Methods
    public List<Event_Master> getProducts(){
        return e_repository.findAll();
    }

    public Event_Master getEventById(long id) {
        return e_repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
    // Delete Product Methods
    public String deleteProduct(long id) {
        e_repository.deleteById(id);
        return "Event Deleted "+ id;
    }
    
    // Update Products Methods
    
    public Event_Master updateProduct(Event_Master event) {
        Event_Master existing_event = getEventById(event.getid());
        existing_event.setstate(event.getstate());
        existing_event.setwaterfall(event.getwaterfall());
        existing_event.setchannelname(event.getchannelname());
        existing_event.setclmsegmentname(event.getclmsegmentname());
        existing_event.setexecutionsequence(event.getexecutionsequence());
        existing_event.setupdatedon(event.getupdatedon());
        existing_event.seteventid(event.geteventid());
        existing_event.setcamptriggerid(event.getcamptriggerid());
        existing_event.setcreativeid1(event.getcreativeid1());
        existing_event.setcampaignid(event.getcampaignid());
        existing_event.setrankedpickliststoryid(event.getrankedpickliststoryid());
        existing_event.setcommunicationcooloff(event.getcommunicationcooloff());
        existing_event.seteventlimit(event.geteventlimit());
        existing_event.setname(event.getname());
        existing_event.setextcreativekey(event.getextcreativekey());
        existing_event.setsenderkey(event.getsenderkey());
        existing_event.settimeslotname(event.gettimeslotname());
        existing_event.settimeslotid(event.gettimeslotid());
        existing_event.setnumberofrecommendation(event.getnumberofrecommendation());
        existing_event.setstartdateid(event.getstartdateid());
        existing_event.setenddateid(event.getenddateid());
        existing_event.setcreative1(event.getcreative1());
        existing_event.setreplacedquery(event.getreplacedquery());
        existing_event.setwebsiteurl(event.getwebsiteurl());
        existing_event.setcampaignthemename(event.getcampaignthemename());
        existing_event.setmicrosegmentname(event.getmicrosegmentname());
        existing_event.setcampaignname(event.getcampaignname());
        existing_event.setdescription(event.getdescription());
        existing_event.setreplacedquerybill(event.getreplacedquerybill());
        existing_event.setrecommendationfilterlogic(event.getrecommendationfilterlogic());
        existing_event.seteventcontrolgrouppercentage(event.geteventcontrolgrouppercentage());
        existing_event.setcommunicationtemplateid(event.getcommunicationtemplateid());
        existing_event.setinsertedon(event.getinsertedon());
        existing_event.seteventtypeid(event.geteventtypeid());
        existing_event.setclmsegmentid(event.getclmsegmentid());
        existing_event.seteventresponsedays(event.geteventresponsedays());
        existing_event.setreminderparenteventid(event.getreminderparenteventid());
        existing_event.setreminderdays(event.getreminderdays());
        existing_event.setarms(event.getarms());
        existing_event.setismabdriven(event.getismabdriven());
        existing_event.setfollowswaterfall(event.getfollowswaterfall());
        existing_event.setisgoodtime(event.getisgoodtime());
        existing_event.setisondemand(event.getisondemand());
        existing_event.setcondition(event.getcondition());
        existing_event.setnoofpersonalization(event.getnoofpersonalization());
        existing_event.setoffercode1(event.getoffercode1());
        
        return e_repository.save(existing_event);
    }
    
    

}
```

Repository

```
package com.example.springbootcrudexample3.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Master;

@Repository
public interface Event_Repository extends JpaRepository<Event_Master,Long>{

}
```

Controller

```
package com.example.springbootcrudexample3.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Master;
import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.service.Event_Service;

@RestController
public class Event_Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Event_Service service;
    
    
    @PostMapping("/addEvent")
    public Event_Master addEvent(@RequestBody Event_Master event) {
        return service.saveEvent(event);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_base
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mysql123
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=8080
logging.level.org.springframework=debug
```

Comment: you are using wrong annotation `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` instead of proper one `javax.persistence.Id`

Comment: Side note (Irrelevant for the functionality of your code): You should use `UpperCamelCase` for classes/types, `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` for constants and `lowerCamelCase` for everything else. This is by convention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `@Id` annotations from the package:
**`javax.persistence.Id`**

`org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` is currently used by Spring to support mapping for other non relational persistence databases or frameworks that do not have a defined common persistence API like JPA

BTW: Your getters and setters are not case sensitive, which is not good practice.